# Execute binary from shell script, and see output in terminal

Tags: bash, scripts, execute-command

I have a binary that outputs to a terminal window when running.
I wish to start this binary from a shell script, because I need to set a environment variable first.

But, when it's executed from:

```
#!/bin/bash
export THIS=set
./binary
```

I can no longer see the binary's output to terminal... How can I get the output while executing with a script?

Answer (score 3):

Solved by

```
./binary | tee /dev/tty
```